# На стороне чего выполняется логика запроса Pandas к Greenplum в Airflow?

Tags: pandas, airflow

Подскажите, пожалуйста:
Есть даг в котором есть таска, которая  берёт sql запрос  и при помощи
 `pandas_df1 = pd.read_sql_query(QUERY1, engine, chunksize=500)` получает датафрейм.
Судя по логам airflow, этот запрос убивается чем-то `/usr/bin/bash: line 1:  3227 Killed`
как раз на моменте выполнения запроса, НО если в самом sql запросе поставить к примеру limit 100, то он выполняется прекрасно. Получается, что как-будто бы проблема в количестве строк, выдаваемых запросом, но есть другие аналогичные запросы, в которых результат по количеству строк намного больше и при этом они прекрасно отрабатывают.

Отсюда и вопрос: на стороне чего выполняется логика запроса в данном случае? На стороне гринплама и пандас уже просто получает готовый результат или какая-то часть логики(или вся) выполняется на стороне пандаса и запрос падает из за этого?  Сам по себе запрос в гринпламе отрабатывает нормально.

Как можно отдебажить проблему?

Заранее спасибо!